# Scroll view not scrolling on API level 26 and further but working on below API level 26

Tags: android, android-layout

I have activity consisting of imageview and textview. within textview i have created 3 links in one sentence and then appended plain text within same textview. text is not fitting within page that is why i added scrollview around textview. but text is only scrolling when i am testing it on below API level 26. means working on API level 21,22,23,24,25. but not working on API level 26,27,28,29.

if i remove code added for sentence consisting link in it then it also works on API level 26 On wards. but i wanted those links in my code.

help will be appreciated. stuck on this many days.

code for textview

```
SpannableStringBuilder stringText=new SpannableStringBuilder("Photo by Paul Hudson licensed under CC BY 2.0");
stringText.setSpan(click1,0,5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
stringText.setSpan(click2,9,21, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
stringText.setSpan(click3,36,45, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
stringText.append(getString(R.string.Lara_Info));
textView.setText(stringText);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

XML code for Scrollview

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrHighestIndividualScore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#FFD740"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:text="@string/Lara_Info"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Show xml for scrollview

Comment: Use `android:autoLink="all"` in xml if you want your links to appear in textview and remove `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`.

Comment: can you please clear your question? where is your code working below API 26 or above API 26? and what you want?

Comment: Hi BlackBlind, i have Imageview and textview on single activity but i am not able to scroll after API 26. i wanted to create fully functional activity on API level 26 onwards also though it is working below API level 26. i have tested it on AVD in android studio.

Comment: Hi Piyush i have edited and placed XML for scrollview

Comment: Hi Sanjeev i tried your suggestion and scrollview got working in API level 26 on wards but links in API level 26 onwards are non clickable though those links i have tried below API level 26 are working properly.